# How does mobile bookmarks works?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, bookmarks, kannel

I have a question about the capabilities of sending mobile bookmarks.

Can I send mobile bookmark with full path - e.g. including non-existing folder, in other words: is it possible to create folder while sending bookmark to mobile ?

I am using `Kannel` server as gateway, and client is developed in java language.

Comment: What do you mean by "bookmark"?

Comment: Following link has some information about the mobile bookmarks. http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.0/userguide-1.4.0/userguide.html#AEN3997

Answer (score 1):

Kannel will only send link as OTA Bookmark without checking if any content available by this URL.

So you should implement this functionality in external application that will do the following:

1. Create catalog or file you want to provide.
2. Send OTA bookmark to mobile handset via Kannel **/cgi-bin/sendota** HTTP API.

Keep in mind that if you prepare URL dynamically then you need to send OTA Bookmark as URL-encoded XML document (**text** instead of **otaid**).